# MapBox studio, style in edit mode does not display the map image

Tags: mapbox

I want to create a map starting from the basic template but when I open the template in the editor I do not see the map.Even in preview mode the map does not appear
In red is where it should appear the map or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

I downloaded json file from mapbox has more than 800 lines of code, it seems that is not empty.

I created a new map from  street template and still not showing nothing in edit mode

[image: mapboxImage]

Comment: This may be related to a bug. If you change the pitch of the map, does this help? You can do this by clicking Map position in the toolbar on the upper right and changing the Pitch value to something low like 0.01.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend deleting that style and creating a new one based on the style `Basic`.  I just attempted what you described and it works fine.

To create a new Style in Mapbox Studio.  You can also follow the [Get started with Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/help/getting-started-mapbox-studio-1/) docs.

- [Login](https://www.mapbox.com/studio/) into Studio
- `Home` > `New Style`
- `Pick a template`, I would recommend starting with `Streets`

To verify, you created a new style based on `Basic` and not on the Style `Empty`, correct?    The screen capture you have above looks like `Empty`.  You can download your Style to compare.

This is what an `Empty` style looks like.  Empty will have no map, giving you the power to build your own map *literally from the ground up*.

```
{
  "version": 8,
  "name": "Empty",
  "metadata": {
    "mapbox:autocomposite": true,
    "mapbox:type": "template"
  },
  "sources": {

  },
  "glyphs": "mapbox://fonts/mapbox/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
  "layers": [
    {
      "id": "background",
      "type": "background",
      "interactive": true,
      "paint": {
        "background-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: ok, I will do as you said, but can you tell me how you created your map?

Comment: I updated my answer, with the steps I did to create a new map.

Comment: The map is not empty because I'm using this map in my leafletjs project, but why not show anything in edit mode? I updated my answer, with new pic from Mapbox

Comment: May need to file a 'help request' with Mapbox.  You can link to the this discussion, since it has your screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing out my video card.  (I worked with Mapbox support for a while but they were unable to help.)  On a whim I swapped out my BFGE Tech GeForce GTS 250 for a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 670 and it started working.

I suspected a hardware issue as the problem persisted after upgrading to Windows 10.